# linq NullReferenceException question

Tags: linq

I have a linq query to a XML dataset, which when executed is generating a NullReferenceException.

XDocument dataDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(e.Result));

```
var Genres = from genre in dataDoc.Descendants("genres")
  where (!genre.Element("ID").IsEmpty)
  select (string)genre.Element("id").Value + ',' + (string)genre.Attribute("name").Value + ',' + (string)genre.Attribute("url").Value;

foreach (string myGenre in Genres)
{
}
```

When executed, the Linq query works fine, but when the code attempts to iterate through the foreach loop, the NullReferenceException occurs.

Now, i *think* that the issue has to do with the XML data I am reading, which looks like the following:

```
<genres>
  <translated>true</translated>
  <genre name="1">
    <id>28</id>
    <url>http://url1</url>
  </genre>
  <genre name="2">
    <id>12</id>
    <url>http://url2</url>
  </genre>
</genres>
```

Is the first child node, which is different in structure, causing the issue?
My class behind this shouldn't be an issue, but is the following (just in case):

```
public class Genre
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your `where` clause should probably be lowercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`genre.Attribute("url")` returns `null`, since there is no `url` attribute.
You need to call `Element`, not `Attribute`.

**EDIT**: Calling `dataDoc.Descendants("genres")` returns the single `<genres>` element, which is not what you want.
You need to call `Descendants("genre")` (singular) to get the individual `<genre ...>` elements.
You could also call `dataDoc.Descendants("genres").Elements` to get the elements inside the `<genres>` element.

Comment: Good catch.  I made that (boneheaded mistake) correction, but I still get the same result.  I also removed the where clause, with no difference.

Comment: Aha!  The edit was the difference!  I think I need to spend some good quality time learning more than just the basics on Linq.  Very useful technology.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

SLaks has pointed out the mistake in using Attribute rather than Element, but there's another improvement you can make in your code. Currently you're using the `Value` property and then redundantly casting to string. If you *just* cast an `XAttribute` or `XElement` to string, then if the original reference is null, the result will be null as well, rather than an exception being thrown. There's no point in using `Value` *and* casting.